# What exactly is 2-Tier architecture?

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, terminology, n-tier-architecture

I understand the 3-Tier architecture very well but not the 2-Tier architecture. I read lot about the differences and still I do not have a clear idea. 
In 2-Tier architecture,

[A Comparison of Two and Three Tier Systems](https://www2.bc.edu/~gallaugh/research/ism95/cccsa.html), says

> Presentation is handled exclusively by the client, processing is split
>   between client and server, and data is stored on and accessed via the
>   server. The PC client assumes the bulk of responsibility for
>   application (functionality) logic with respect to the processing
>   component, while the database engine - with its attendant integrity
>   checks, query capabilities and central repository functions - handles
>   data intensive tasks.

So when we compare this with JSP/Servlet development, does this mean we do not use any Servlets and all the Server Side code is written in JSP itself using Scripting Elements? Which means we will only have JSPs in our application. Does data access code also written in the JSP? So then, is this the 2-Tier architecture? 
I want to compare it with JSP/Servlet development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose a very simple example of this would be a GUI application running on a PC talking to a remote database (2 workers = 2 tiers). There's no JSP because the GUI is doing everything the JSP would do (talk to the database, format the data, etc).

Answer (score 1):

A 2-tier architecture is also called [Client-Server-Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) the difference to 3-tier is that the business-logic is not in a business-layer, some of business logic might be implemented in the client and some in the server.

As long you do the DB access by your JSPs you have 2-tier. Implementing business-locig in EJBs would make it 3-tier.

Answer (score 0):

The term 2-tier architecture is more relevant to (but not limited to) applications developed during non-internet era, prior to late nineties. **Examples:** GUI applications built on VB, Oracle Forms, Smalltalk etc that talk to database using ODBC drivers.

A JSP/Servlet based application involving data (CRUD operations) *usually* has three tiers involved - a browser (for GUI), HTTP server (along with servlet engine) and database server. In java world, a better comparison could be a swing application connecting to database server using JDBC.